# Using python for loop to average data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have a data set that contains 20 years of monthly averages in a numpy array with dimensions (1x240). I'm trying to write a function to spit out the yearly averages. I've managed to do it (I believe), using a for loop, but when I stick the exact same code into a function, it only gives me the first of what should be 20 values.

```
def yearlymean_gm(gm_data):
    data= np.load(gm_data)
        for i in range (0,20):
        average= data[i*12:i*12+12].sum()/12
        print average
        return average
```

gm_data is the name of the file.

When I simply manually enter

```
data= np.load(gm_data)
for i in range (0,20):
    average= data[i*12:i*12+12].sum()/12
    print average
    return average
```

it successfully reads out the 20 values. I'm pretty sure I just don't quite understand how for loops work in the context of functions. Any explanation (and a fix, if possible), would be awesome.

Secondly, I would love to have these values fed into an numpy array. I tried

```
def yearlymean_gm(gm_data):
    data= np.load(gm_data)
    average = np.zeroes(20)  
    for i in range (0,20):
        average[i]= data[i*12:i*12+12].sum()/12
        print average
        return average
```

but this gives me a long, wacky, list. Help on this would be cool too. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find one. You have your `return` inside your `for` loop body so it only completes one iteration. Then the function is over so the rest of your loop is kaput.

Comment: Something's off with the indentation in your examples. Also, the second block of code contains a `return` but it's not in a function.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm sure there's plenty but they never have a title that makes it easy to track down :) Indentation is invalid though, so I'm not sure we can confirm that this is the cause.

Comment: @roganjosh As written, returning early from a loop is exactly what BenL described. This is almost certianly the problem

Comment: An aggregate dataset via pandas might give you the results your looking for (and wouldn't require iterative logic). I can provide additional details if you'd like - just let me know.

Comment: @Sevyns he's on the right track for what he wants to calculate... he just needs to unindent his return statement

Comment: 420 rep.... BLAZE IT :D

Comment: @Aaron true, it certainly points to that, but it should be confirmed first before tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what you need...

```
def yearlymean_gm(gm_data):
    data= np.load(gm_data)
    average = np.zeroes(20)  
    for i in range (0,20):
        average[i]= data[i*12:i*12+12].sum()/12
        print average
    return average  #don't return until the loop has completed
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not avoid the "for" loop altogether?

```
def yearlymean_gm(gm_data):
    data = np.load(gm_data)
    data = data.reshape((12, 20))
    print data.mean(axis=1)
    return data.mean(axis=1)
```